# How to do an action after callback in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

How to fire the final console.log AFTER the callback is finished.

```
var nodePandoc = require('node-pandoc');
var src, args;
 
src = 'Lesson.docx';
args = '-f docx -t markdown -o ./Lesson.md';

callback = function (err, result) {
  if (err) console.error('Oh No: ',err);
  return console.log("callback result:",result), result;
};

nodePandoc(src, args, callback);

console.log("Conversion finished, you can call function to move the file around");
```

Comment: Run it from the callback?

Comment: @robertklep unfortunately a console.log between the if(err) and the return line in callback gets fired before the callback result

Comment: You can leave out the return, it's moot anyway.

Comment: Thank @robertklep, but nope, commenting the return line still results in wrong console.log order.

Comment: You know you can change their order, right…?

Comment: @robertklep Actually no. I can't find the way to have the conversion finished BEFORE moving the file around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to just log the final line from within the callback:

```
var nodePandoc = require('node-pandoc');
var src, args;
 
src = 'Lesson.docx';
args = '-f docx -t markdown -o ./Lesson.md';

callback = function (err, result) {
  if (err) return console.error('Oh No: ',err);
  console.log("callback result:",result);
  console.log("Conversion finished, you can call function to move the file around");
};

nodePandoc(src, args, callback);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I now understand what you meant about "no need for the return". Perfect.